# How to download the audio file instead of streaming

Tags: html

I have created a website where I have created a download link but problem is when I click on download link it will streaming the audio but I want that if user clicked the download button it will directly download the file.

```
<a href="http://admin.jainjainism.com/MP3Uploads/%20की%20सार्थकता%20नियमों%20से%20और%20नियमों%20की%20सार्थकता%20समता%20भाव%20से%20है।.mp3" download></a>
<a href="http://admin.jainjainism.com/MP3Uploads/%20की%20सार्थकता%20नियमों%20से%20और%20नियमों%20की%20सार्थकता%20समता%20भाव%20से%20है।.mp3" download="try.mp3"></a>
```

I have tried but result are same